# Poisson distribution application

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Let $X$ be the number of trains arriving on a given day. We are given that $X$ is Poisson with $\lambda = 12$. We are asked to find $P(X<9)$. But, we know

$$ P(X<9) = \sum_{x=0}^9 \frac{ 12^x e^{-12} }{x!} = e^{-12} \times \sum_{x=0}^9 \frac{12^x}{x!} \approx e^{-12 } \cdot e^{12} = 1 $$

But the answer given is $0.1550$. How is that possible since we know

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x $$

and if we take say $9$ terms like in our problem then the series is almost close to $e^x$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hi, what book is this from?

Comment: http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/Pbook.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 12)$ and you seek 
$P(X < 9) = P(X \le 8) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^8 \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}.$

In R statistical software this is: $P(X \le 8) = 0.1550$ to four places
as claimed.

```
ppois(8, 12)
[1] 0.1550278
```

The infinite sum does converge as you say, but 8 is a long way from $\infty.$
The precise computation adding terms agrees.

```
i = 0:8;  exp(-12)*sum(12^i/factorial(i)) 
[1] 0.1550278
```

However, if we sum 31 terms, we get very nearly 1:

```
i = 0:30;  exp(-12)*sum(12^i/factorial(i)) 
[1] 0.9999966
```

And if we sum 51 terms, the sum is so close to 1 that R prints that as the answer, to the direct computation. However, $P(X > 50) > 0.$ According to this Poisson model, if you wait for
a day with more than 50 trains, you'll wait for quite a while.

```
i = 0:50;  exp(-12)*sum(12^i/factorial(i)) 
[1] 1

1 - ppois(50, 12)
[1] 1.110223e-16
```